# How can I match the number of characters in RegEx exactly in this situation?

Tags: php, regex

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $db_id, $dbpw);
$db= new PDO($dsn, $db_id, $dbpw);
```

I want to get exactly the variable name '$db'.

Other variable names starting with $db should be excluded.

I wrote the following regular expression:

```
/(\$db)[^_a-zA-Z0-9]/g
```

So '$db_id' and '$dbpw' were excluded as I intended.

However, just to the right of $db, one character(space, =, etc.) is matched 'more' like this: '$db ', '$db='

This is not my intention. How can I match exactly '$db' in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [word boundary (`\b`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
/(\$db)\b/
```

---

According to [Regex Tutorial - `\b` Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a
>     word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last
>     character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string,
>     where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.
>
> Simply put: \b allows you to perform a "whole words only" search using
>   a regular expression in the form of \bword\b. A "word character" is a
>   character that can be used to form words. All characters that are not
>   "word characters" are "non-word characters".

Comment: Thank you. I've studied regular expressions on some websites, but I did not know a metacharacter called \ b. I'll study more.

Comment: There is no `g` flag with php.

Comment: @Toto, Thank you for pointing it out, I removed the `g` flag.